# onLoadFinished() is not called after orientation change or after device is locked

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I am using loader in my application to perform background operation.As i want to support Orientation and Locale and other configuration changes i prefer to choose Loader.

In my application i have a list where user can select multiple list items process some action when he click on action mode item.I want to perform/ process this action every time when ever user click on this action mode item.As i am processing the data to file in sd card ,i do not want to save the data inside loader once the operation is done.

The Loader written below is working fine as expected when there is no orientation change or when the activity is on top.

When there is orientation change/ activity is in background ,onLoadFinished() is not called.As a result progress is visible  always.From the observation found that onLoadFinished is not called though it delivers the result.

i do not want to  init/restart the loader again and again.as i have a dependency of passing the selected list items.

Can any one please suggest me how to make sure onLoadFinished() is called always after loadInBackground.TIA.

CODE:

LOADER CALLBACK CLASS :

```
class ExtractingLoaderManager implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<String> {

    private List<Integer> mSelectionList;

    ExtractingLoaderManager(List<Integer> list) {
        mSelectionList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<String> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        showProgressBar();
        return new ExtractLoader(MyActivity.this, mSelectionList, mListAdapter, progressDialog);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<String> loader, String data) {
        Logger.i(TAG, "EL : onLoadFinished");

        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        data =null;
        dismissProgressBar();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<String> loader) {

    }
}
```

CALLED FROM ACTION MODE ITEM CLICKED :

```
@Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_extract) {
        //Logger.i(TAG, "onActionItemClicked: Extract");
        ArrayList<Integer> mArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        mArrayList.addAll(mListAdapter.getSelectedList());
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(4, null, new ExtractingLoaderManager(mArrayList));
        mode.finish();
    }
```

LOADER CLASS :

```
public class ExtractLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<String> {

private static final String TAG = ExtractLoader.class.getSimpleName();
private List<Integer> mList, mTempList;

private Context mContext;
private ListAdapter mAdapter;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
String message = null;

ExtractLoader(Context context, List<Integer> list, ListAdapter adapter, ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
    super(context);

    mList = list;
    mAdapter = adapter;
    mContext = context;
    this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
}

@Override
protected void onStartLoading() {
    Logger.i(TAG, "EL :onStartoading : " + takeContentChanged() + " : " + message);

    if (takeContentChanged() || message == null) {
        Logger.i(TAG, "EL : onStartoading : forceLoad");
        forceLoad();
    }
}

@Override
public String loadInBackground() {
    Logger.i(TAG, "EL :loadInBackground");

    for (int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i++) {
        new Utils().letsExtract(mAdapter.getData().get(mList.get(i)));
        publish(i);
    }
    if (mList.size() == 1) {
        message = new String("single entry /  Success condition");
    } else {
        message = new String("Multiple entry / some other condition");
    }
    return message;
}

public void publish(int i) {
    Logger.i(TAG, "EL :publish Progress: " + i);

}

@Override
protected void onForceLoad() {
    super.onForceLoad();
    Logger.i(TAG, "onForceLoadCalled");
}


@Override
public void stopLoading() {
    cancelLoad();
    Logger.i(TAG, "EL :stopLoading");
}

@Override
protected void onReset() {
    Logger.i(TAG, "EL :onReset");
    stopLoading();
}

@Override
public void deliverResult(String data) {
    if (isReset()) {
        return;
    }

    if (isStarted()) {
        super.deliverResult(data);
        Logger.i(TAG, "EL :deliverResult");
    }
}
}
```

EDIT :

As the listner is not attached to the laoder i am starting loader in onCreate and restarting the loader in onActionItemCLicked().
This solved me the problem of loader when there is orientation is changed.

Still the issue exists when device is locked and unlocked ,and user resumes activity loader onLoadFinished is not called.